# Jquery Change parent height when childs is visible

Tags: jquery, html

Building a fill up form with my friends.

That when got some fill up error, and the input-error pop up, that will change the input-error height so will push down the fill up form.

I want to change the parent height when the child attr is visible;

that is what i test but somehow doesnt work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($("#txtFullName").attr("visibility","visible")){
        $("#txtFullName").parent().css("height","30px");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is it an attribute? You not setting it with CSS?

Comment: `visibility` isn't a valid HTML attribute. Do you mean to be checking the CSS style?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($("#txtFullName").attr("visibility")==="visible"){
        $("#txtFullName").parent().css("height","30px");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($("#txtFullName").attr("visibility","visible")) {
        $("#txtFullName").parent().css("height","30px");
   }
});
</script>
```

You are missing a closing bracket for your `if` condition. visibility is also a css property, so you need to use `$("#txtFullName").css("visibility")`.

passing a second argument for `.css` and `.attr` denotes that you are setting the value of that property. `$("#txtFullName").css("visibility")` should suffice.

one thing to note as well when using visibility is that an element with visibility set as hidden is not visible but still retains the space it takes. So you will see an empty space where it is originally rendered.

you can also use `.is(":visible")` method to check if an element is visible or not. example, `$("#txtFullName").is(":visible")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($("#txtFullName").is(":visible")) {
        $("#txtFullName").parent().css("height","30px");
   }
   else {
        $("#txtFullName").parent().css("height","0px");
   }
});
```

use of `is` condition would help out for your requirement i belief.

Answer (score 1):

Since *visibility* isn't valid HTML attribute you should use .is(":visible").

However, in .NET environment *visibility* is an attribute that is used. As is *hidden*. But those are .NET's own attributes, not HTML's and therefore jQuery might not be able to detect them.

The .is(":visible") method checks if the selected element is visible. No matter how it might be hid or displayed.

```
if($("#txtFullName").is(":visible")){
  $("#txtFullName").parent().css("height","30px");
}
```